# No index defined in MySQL wp_postmeta and wp_posts

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress

I've got a problem with WordPress. I can't see my Media in Grid View (instead I see all the uploads in list view, but I "can't upload" new files. The message is:

> An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later.

I only see a grey thumbnail and the name of file become (No title) - Logo .

I've tried all the mainstream solutions (permissions, increase memory on php.ini, etc etc but nothing to do, the problem stay there).

So I've installed WordPress from zero in another domain that I had and linked the database of the website that I've talked above. No plug-in active, standard theme active and the problem stay there.

So I realized the problem is in DB and when I go to wp_posts and wp_postmeta I saw "no index defined" error.

P.S. I'm not an expert of SQL, Query and this kind of code. P.S. The problem started when I upgrade WordPress to the latest version (4.9.4). I don't remember the old version that I had online. I've tried also a downgrade.

Comment: Brando -check the errors you get in firebug console

Comment: If I check on Firefox I only see this error:This site appears to use a scroll-linked positioning effect. This may not work well with asynchronous panning; see https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Performance/ScrollLinkedEffects for further details and to join the discussion on related tools and features!
upload.php